# Failed to link Android resources on real device

Tags: flutter, dart

I specified an icon in AndroidManifest.xml and everything works fine on the emulator, but when I try to run it on a real device I get an error -

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/home/daniil/StudioProjects/postterminal/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:33: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/app_icon (aka com.example.postterminal:mipmap/app_icon) not found.
```

here is my /home/daniil/StudioProjects/postterminal/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml - [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqysk.png)

and here is my proj/android/app/src/main -

```
<activity 
            android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"....
</activity>
```

Tell me what is my mistake and how to fix it?

piece of code where I use the icon -

```
final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
```

Comment: you added this in drawable24 , you need to add drawable folder

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Should I delete the question?

Comment: no it may be helpful for others too . please upvote my comment

Comment: Sorry, I can't add a voice. Maybe you can write an answer?

Comment: answer added please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you added this in `drawable24` ,

you need to add **drawable** folder